# I needn't have done for an action that wasn't done

Tags: modal-verbs, british-english

Would it be wrong (in BrE) to say that when something was done but it wasn't necessary only "needn't have done" is used but it is not used for an action that wasn't done? For example, "I needn't have bought another loaf of bread. We already had one." (I bought it). If I didn't buy a loaf of bread or even if I bought it but it wasn't necessary I can use either "I didn't need to" and " didn't have to". Am I right?

Comment: You raise an interesting point! If you ***needn't have** [done something]*, that *always* implies you did actually do it, even though it wasn't necessary. But saying you ***didn't need** [to do it]* (or *didn't **have** to*) is "agnostic" as to whether you did it or not (though *in context*, it'll almost always be obvious whether you did or didn't do it). But note that in spoken contexts, there would often be very heavy stress on *didn't **need** to do it* to imply that you actually ***did*** do it (where the very heavily stressed alternative ***have*** would often be pronounced ***HAFF***).

Comment: (That's to say, for most speakers, *You needn't have done that* and *You didn't **haff** to do that* are equivalently unambiguous - you did indeed do it, but it would have been *possible* for you not to have done it.)

Comment: Thank you! But are "didn't have to" and "didn't need to" interchangeable? For example, these sentences are from Michael Vince's "English Grammar in Context".  1. "Of course, in ancient times athletes didn't have to take drug tests."
2. "In ancient Greece, winning athletes didn't need to work again."  Would "need to" work in sentence 1? and "have to"  in sentence 2?

Comment: In those two examples, ***have*** and ***need*** are equivalent & interchangeable. But in *in ancient times athletes didn't have / need to take drug tests,* they had no choice (they *couldn't* be tested, because there *were* no such tests). Whereas *winning athletes didn't have / need to work again* specifically implies they had a choice (it's a matter of opinion and *exact* context whether in practice they always chose *not* to work again after surviving one round of contests).

Comment: ...on the other hand, *winning athletes needn't have worked again* is an an unlikely thing to say, but it carries the strong implication that they invariably *did* go back into the arena, even if they weren't ***forced*** to.

Comment: This is another explanation written by a native speaker under this comment. You said it's a matter of opinion. In this explanation I read that they are not interchangeable. Sometimes native speakers think we learners argue with them. I am definitely  not arguing. As a non-native speaker I am trying to understand the difference between them. To make it easier for me to understand can I sum up and say that "have to" is not only limited to obligations and as you said  (unlike a native speaker whose  comment I posted  who said that they are not interchangeable).

Comment: need to" wouldn't work in sentence 1. No one "needs" to take a drug test - it's an obligation if you're a professional athlete. It's something you have to do. 
"have to" wouldn't work in sentence 2. No one has to work. It's optional. As it stands, the sentence makes it clear that athletes had no need to work. Whether this is because they won a lot of money or because, as champions, they were given everything they needed to live isn't clear.

Comment: Am I to understand that Michael Vince claims that *In ancient times athletes didn't need to take drug tests* and *Winning athletes didn't have to work again* are somehow "incorrect"? If so, all I can say is I think that's rubbish! There can be a *slight* difference of emphasis depending on the ***have/need*** choice. But frankly I doubt even most native speakers would recognise and be able to describe any such differences, so for a non-native speaker it's quite enough to just say they're interchangeable.

Comment: I think so. Those are the examples from his book. But what I copied and pasted was written by another native speaker who says that they are not interchangeable.  I am talking about the original two sentences. There is another example in his book "At least I managed to do it without working at the weekend." The book says the correct answer is "I didn't need to work" not "I didn't have to work." Would it be OK to upload screenshots?

Comment: I don't want to get bogged down in endless "He said, She said" to-and-froing here. I don't accept the distinction claimed in your "without working at the weekend" example. But apparently *some* people do. It really isn't worth your trouble to spend time on this simply because you want to learn English "well" - the mere fact that I as a competent native speaker (with a degree in English Language & Literature! :) don't accept it is enough to make it at the very least a "matter of opinion". But if you're interested *because it's interesting*, you could certainly raise the issue on ELU.

Comment: ...you might find [this ELU comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/276394/why-do-the-sentences-i-have-to-get-a-job-and-i-need-to-get-a-job-mean-the-sa?rq=1#comment610607_276395) (describing the relevant *tendency*, not an actual "rule") interesting and/or useful. There's also an Answer from John Lawler on that page, and I'd hesitate to disagree with anything ***he*** says (but I don't see anything there about this particular "distinction").

Comment: No, I am not going to ask another question. Knowing your opinion is enough for me. You have already helped me many times with such confusing grammar issues. Thank you!!!